# undefined local variable in nested resource form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a nested resource form with simple_form.

I have two classes:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one    :product_review, dependent: :destroy
end

class ProductReview < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I added the routes and in my routes I have

```
                  admin_product_product_reviews GET      /admin/products/:product_id/product_reviews(.:format)                                   admin/product_reviews#index
                                                POST     /admin/products/:product_id/product_reviews(.:format)                                   admin/product_reviews#create
               new_admin_product_product_review GET      /admin/products/:product_id/product_reviews/new(.:format)                               admin/product_reviews#new
              edit_admin_product_product_review GET      /admin/products/:product_id/product_reviews/:id/edit(.:format)                          admin/product_reviews#edit
                   admin_product_product_review GET      /admin/products/:product_id/product_reviews/:id(.:format)                               admin/product_reviews#show
                                                PATCH    /admin/products/:product_id/product_reviews/:id(.:format)                               admin/product_reviews#update
                                                PUT      /admin/products/:product_id/product_reviews/:id(.:format)                               admin/product_reviews#update
                                                DELETE   /admin/products/:product_id/product_reviews/:id(.:format)                               admin/product_reviews#destroy
```

I need to create a form to build and edit the product_review.

I create a button:

```
= link_to new_admin_product_product_review_path(product)
```

And I create the form

```
= simple_form_for [product,product_review], url: admin_product_product_review_path do |form|
```

but it returns to me the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `product' for #<#<Class:0x007fbaf54d1720>:0x007fbae974ea90>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You relation association is wrong. If you have "has_one" in one model then you should also have "belongs_to" in the other.

Then you should find a product that you want to add review to. "@product"

Then build review for than product. build_association

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

model

```
class ProductReview < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
end
```

controller

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
```

view

```
form_for (@product,@product.build_product_review)
```

Comment: this answer would greatly benefit from some additional explanation